# A simple way to create a single file artifact using maven?

Tags: maven, maven-package

I'd like to create an single file artifact. Don't care if it's wrapped by an archive file.

Is there a way to do it without creating a new maven-plugin or without using an additional assembly xml file?

* Full code (XMLs) would be appreciated.

Comment: The reason I don't want to create an assembly file is because it bloats the folder. Instead of just a single file, which is the most important thing, I'll have a `pom.xml` and `assembly.xml` to explain how to package it. Looks like way too much effort.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain so others could learn from your feedback.

Comment: What kind of artifact would you like to create ? An jar ? Or a ZIP file? I don't know why you are talking about a assembly.xml ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, doesn't matter what archive it is. If not assembly, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xml reference can be found here:
[How to specify files to be deployed in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959906/how-to-specify-files-to-be-deployed-in-maven)

fine tuning and command line experimentation:
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.xyz -DartifactId=zyx-component -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dfile=test.log -Dpackaging=log

mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.xyz -DartifactId=zyx-component -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dfile=test.log -Dpackaging=log -Durl=http://my.nexus.url

Comment: Packaging as `log` changes the file's suffix. I changed the package to the file's suffix and the suffix was kept. `-Dpackaging=jks` worked fine.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892612/install-file-using-pom-instead-of-commandline